# How to make an Android Studio Bluetooth Connection App

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

We're trying to make an app which will connect to a car's bluetooth and play audio on the phone. I have not had much luck finding help on this on the internet. Can someone lead me in the right direction on where we should look or what we should do?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Android Auto.

https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/auto

https://developer.android.com/training/cars/media/automotive-os

But if you don't want that and just want to use only bluetooth, you can have a look over here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth